# *ngIf está renderizando dois blocos

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Estou fazendo uma validação de inputs, onde caso o usuário selecione o banco X, o campo conta terá no mínimo 5 caracteres e no máximo 11, caso escolha o banco Y, o campo terá no mínimo 5 caracteres e no máximo 5. Está assim a div:

```html
//Banco X
<div *ngIf="form.get("id_banco")?.value !== codigo_y">
  <input
    maxlength="11"
    minlength="5"
    formControlName="conta"
  >
</div>

//Banco Y
<div *ngIf="form.get("id_banco")?.value === codigo_y">
  <input
    maxlength="5"
    minlength="5"
    formControlName="conta"
  >
</div>
```

Caso eu seleciono o banco X, ele aceita mais de 5 caracteres, mas apresenta uma mensagem de erro que eu havia colocado e se eu volto com 5 caracteres, o erro some. E se eu altero o banco Y para aceitar 8 caracteres, no banco X ele também só fica valido com 8 caracteres. Alguma sugestão? Se for preciso mais informações, podem me falar.

Comment: Acho que deveria dar mais informações, embora eu acho que o problema seja nos **if's**, a comparação deveria ser com strings `...value === 'codigo_y' "` certo?

Comment: tente alterar de: *ngIf="form.get("id_banco")?.value !== codigo_y" para *ngIf="form.get('id_banco')?.value !== 'codigo_y'".
Faça isso nos 2 inputs, provavelmente esse é só um erro de digitação, abrindo o ngif com aspas duplas e fechado ela quando você vai informar o parametro da função get, use aspas simples para os argumentos que vai passar após já ter aberto as aspas duplas.

Comment: @Paz mesmo codigo.y sendo um number teria que ter as aspas simples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a única diferença é o `maxlength`, ficaria mais sucinto fazer isto:

```
<div>
  <input
    [maxLength]="form.get("id_banco")?.value === codigo_y ? 5 : 11"
    minLength="5"
    formControlName="conta"
  >
</div>
```

Mas como já disseram nos comentários, verifique se os itens comparados têm o mesmo tipo.

Comment: Seria muito bom cara, mas ainda não funcionou, recebo um erro "Opening tag "input" not terminated"...sabe se é preciso importar algo no app.module?

Comment: E os itens são do tipo number, não teria problema com isso...

Comment: O erro que você está tendo é de digitação... Veja se o `>` está presente.

Comment: Está sim, tentei fechar a tag input, mas continua o mesmo erro

Comment: Encontrei o erro, faltou as ' ' no 5 e 11, obrigadão!! Deu certo

Comment: Legal, fico feliz.